# OracleXmlType in Grails

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

I'm attempting to map a domain object's member type to OracleXmlType.  I've followed Graeme Rocher's suggestion 
[here](http://archive.montage.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.grails.scm/msg/13379562.1199702277466.JavaMail.haus-jira@codehaus01.managed.contegix.com) regarding adding xmlparserv2.jar to the classpath, as well as [this post](http://markmail.org/message/5qadkqhfperl7i3w#query%3aOracleXmlType%20grails+page:1+mid:3viybuhpqv2ux5zo+state%3aresults) describing how to declare the static mapping.  If I start Grails with

> grails -cp %ORACLE_LIBS%/xmlparserv2.jar run-app

I get the following:

```
2010-12-07 11:25:41,532 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap"
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap"
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap"
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
        at grails.spring.DynamicElementReader.invokeMethod(DynamicElementReader.groovy:121)
        ... 26 more
```

Starting grails with this (add xdb.jar to the classpath):

```
>grails -cp %ORACLE_LIBS%/xmlparserv2.jar:%ORACLE_LIBS%/xdb.jar run-app
```

results in this:

```
Running Grails application..
2010-12-07 11:15:23,497 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.mydomain.DropFile]:  No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.mydomain.DropFile]:  No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block
for domain [com.mydomain.DropFile]:  No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.mydomain.DropFile]:  No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.mydomain.DropFile]:  No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        ... 23 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: OracleXmlType for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder
        at com.mydomain.DropFile$__clinit__closure2.doCall(DropFile.groovy:24)
        at com.mydomain.DropFile$__clinit__closure2.doCall(DropFile.groovy)
        ... 23 more
```

If I use the same classpath as my last invocation, and change my mapping to this:

```
static mapping = {
    xmlContent type:"OracleXmlType" // quotes around OracleXmlType
}
```

... I get this:

```
Running Grails application..
2010-12-07 11:30:24,589 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: OracleXmlType, at table: drop_file, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(xml_content)]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: OracleXmlType, at table: drop_file, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(xml_content)]
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
        at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: OracleXmlType, at table: drop_file, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(xml_content)]
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: OracleXmlType, at table: drop_file, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(xml_content)]
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: OracleXmlType, at table: drop_file, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(xml_content)]
        ... 23 more
```

The second and third attempts seem close.  Could anyone shed some light on what I'm missing?  Do I have to provide an implementation of OracleXmlType?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix it, but that sounds a lot like an issue I had with using XDB from a JSF application in glassfish.  The problem was xmlparserv2.jar registers an older XML library than doesn't work with some server components.

Create a temp directory, unjar xmlparserv2.jar into it, remove the META-INF/services directory, and then jar it back up.  Now deploy that modified jar file with application and see if it helps.